# Unexpected directive 'LoginComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, meteor

I'm using Angular 2 and Meteor. Generating Components produces the following error:

> Unexpected directive 'LoginComponent' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

the app.module.ts file is

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from '../../components/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from '../../components/signup/signup.component';
import { ResourcesComponent } from '../../components/resources/resources.component'; 
import { NavbarComponent } from '../../components/navbar/navbar.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    ResourcesComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports:[BrowserModule,
  LoginComponent,
  SignupComponent,
  ResourcesComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [MyApp]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and the login.component.ts file is

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from "./login.html";

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  template
})
export class LoginComponent {}
```

Comment: why are you adding the components into the imports array in AppModule?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

In an `NgModule.imports`, you can only list modules. Not components.  So the problem is here:

```
imports:[BrowserModule, LoginComponent, SignupComponent, ResourcesComponent ]
```

Remove the components, and take a look at the [NgModules FAQ](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#ngmodule-faqs)

> #### What should I import?
>
> Import modules whose public (exported) declarable classes you need to reference in this module's component templates